# asp.net customized menu per item

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

I have a small ASP.NET application (.NET Framework 4) and I need to build a website menu with different items having different styles. Something like this:

- ENTRY 1 --> css class "first";
- ENTRY 2 --> css class "second";
- ENTRY 3 --> css class "third";

They are basically identical, the only difference is the hovering color. Under the hood, the ASP.NET always generates a html-link like this:

My question is - can I change the the class of the main link for each entry in the menu?

I already tried something like this:

```
<div class="topNav">
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" 
    runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="false" 
    IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
    Orientation="Horizontal" 
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" 
    StaticDisplayLevels="1">

    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" Value="first">
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" Value="second"/>
    </Items>
    <StaticItemTemplate>
        <span class="<%#Eval("Value") %>"><%#Eval("Text") %></span>
    </StaticItemTemplate>
    <DynamicItemTemplate>
        <span class="<%#Eval("Value") %>"><%#Eval("Text") %></span>
    </DynamicItemTemplate>
</asp:Menu>
```

but because there is a span automatically generated inside the link - the layout of the page is not correct. The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="level1">
  <li>
    <a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">
      <span class="first">Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="level1" href="About.aspx">
      <span class="second">About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It would have been nice to drop the "level1" from "a" tag and replace it with "first"/"second" (and span tag to go away).

So ... any hint/idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery this way:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function FixAnchor(cls) {
            $('a.level1:has(' + "." + cls + ')').each(function () {
                $(this).text = $('span' + '.' + cls ).html();
                $(this).removeClass('level1').addClass(cls );
                $('span' +'.' + cls).removeClass(cls);
            })
        }

        FixAnchor('first');
        FixAnchor('second');
    });
</script>
```

And don't forget to add reference to jquery in the head of the page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try! I was hoping for something made directly in the code ...